# Rails 3: jquery working to switch view with AJAX, how to get an focused state for the link?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

just got my views to change with AJAX, but now I'm stumped on how to make the action requested to have a :focus type css option so that when a user selects "About" and the _about partial load, I can have the "About" link with a style to show it's the About page. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a class on the clicked link, removing that same class from all the other links. For example:

```
$('a.tab_link').click(function(){
  $('a.tab_link').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active')
})

// CSS
a.tab_link.active {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: looking good! so this would only apply to the links I add class="tab_link" to? what does $(this) refer to? thanks

Comment: Yes. `$(this)` returns the JQuery object for the link that was clicked on.

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to get this working. Could you include a jsfiddle for me to see? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a helper like this in your application_helper.rb

```
  def  nav_link(name, url)
    selected = url.all? { |key, value| params[key] == value }
    link_to(name, url, :class => (selected ? "youarehere tabs" : "tabs"))
  end
```

then in your view you can have

```
<div id="menu-header">
       <div class="subheader answers-subheader">
        <div id="tabs" class="tabs2">
          <%= nav_link "example", :view => nil %>
          <%= nav_link "example1", :view => "example1"%>
          <%= nav_link "example2", :view => "example2" %>
        </div>
       </div>
</div>

  <div id="menu-items">
     <%= %w[example example1 example2 ].include?(params[:view]) ? render(params[:view]) : render("example") %>
  </div>
```

then in your application.js you can have

```
$(function() {
    $(".tabs2 .tabs").click(function(e) {
      $("#tabs .tabs").removeClass("youarehere");
      $(this).addClass("youarehere");
      $("#menu-items").append('<div class="progress"><img src="/assets/loading.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="" /></div>');
      $.getScript(this.href);
      if (history && history.replaceState) {
        history.replaceState(null, document.title, this.href);
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

i hope this helps